# Add custom toolbar buttons to HtmlEditorExtender and set style sheet

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I’m upgrading an ASP.NET solution from AjaxControlToolkit **V4**.x to **V17**.x. The original HTMLEditor was deprecated and **HtmlEditorExtender** shall now be used instead. My HTML editor contains a few **custom toolbar buttons**, which need to be migrated. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find any examples on how to add custom toolbar buttons to the HtmlEditorExtender.

An example on how to add a toolbar button „H1“, which applies the **h1** style to the selected text would be very helpful.

Also, HTMLEditor offered these properties to set a specific **style sheet**  (which can be selected by the user dynamically at runtime):

```
htmlEditorEx.DesignPanelCssPath
htmlEditorEx.DocumentCssPath
```

Is there an equivalent in HtmlEditorExtender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can extend a `HtmlEditorExtenderButton` class, HtmlEditorExtender's client code has no logic that runs custom client behavior of a button.

I see the only valid option is to extend `HtmlEditorExtender` itself and add your custom logic [to a client code that executes button logic](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/Scripts/HtmlEditorExtender.js#L358-L601).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After spending hours with the HtmlEditorExtender, I decided to go with a commercial editor. Your reply backs that decision.